# Using choices together with user input in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a model with fields that will provide choices for the user so I am using keyword `choices` like this:

```
ACQUIRED_FROM=(
    ('dealer', 'Dealer'),
    ('private', 'Private'),
    ('show', 'Show'),
    ('family member', 'Family Member'),
    ('other', 'Other'),),
```

and specifying the field like this:

```
acquired_from = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACQUIRED_FROM)
```

Under family member I need the user to input the specific person (e.g. father, uncle, e.t.c).

I think it will also apply to a currency field that will enable the user to choose whether the input is in dollars or euros and then specifying the amount.

The question is how can I define the choices to enable user input?

This is a simpler way to ask the same question above:

```
LENGTH=(
    ('CENTIMETERS', 'cm'),
    ('INCHES', 'in'),),
```

With this I would like the user to select either inches or centimeters and then input the actual value. How should I modify it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Django has support for nested choices. See the second example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: You have to use jquery to make the input field more dynamic when selecting choice in the dropdown menu...

Comment: @Selcuk I used that example but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Django [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices) is not meant for dynamic content.
If your intention is to build `nested choices` (aka `group choices`), you can pre-define the list of choices for `family member` the same as you defined it for `acquired_from`.

```
ACQUIRED_FROM = (
    ('dealer', 'Dealer'),
    ('private', 'Private'),
    ('show', 'Show'),
    ('Family Member', (
            ('father', 'Father'),
            ('uncle', 'Uncle'),
         )
    ),
    ('other', 'Other'),
)
```

Comment: father and uncle are not the only options that is why am not using nested choices. Other than Django choices is there any other way to define such input?

Comment: can you pre-define all options for family member? or are they dynamic?

Comment: Predefining the family members will limit the user since I can't capture all of them.

Comment: @PhilloPeters so you're saying that user can choose from `['father', 'uncle', 'mother', etc.]` or enter his/her own choice?

Comment: The user to enter his/her own choice